# Linux DVB V5 library - example code for EIT grabbing

Tags: linux, dvb, epg

I am just starting to use the DVB V5 library for a project.

I am trying to find any example code to show it being used for EIT grabbing, if anyone knows of / has any.

Comment: entering this as a comment instead of an answer because it's slightly off-topic:  I maintain a different library `libdvbtee` hosted at http://github.com/mkrufky/libdvbtee that specializes in capture of EPG data.  It might not fulfill all of your needs, but it's a worthy piece of code to look at and play with.

Comment: Magic. I'll have a look, thanks.

Comment: ... actually I have now managed to get some EIT data (testing with BBC 2 HD), but it seems the name / description is encrypted or at least encoded in some way. Lots of strange characters.

Comment: EIT in Europe is usually in cleartext.  Might your data be bitshifted?  In the states, ATSC broadcast EIT tables titles and descriptions are Huffman encoded.

Comment: Unfortunately it is definitely encoded. It is Huffman encoding but each decoded character indexes a new Huffman decode table, so it is definitely for encryption rather than simply compression. It applies to the multiplexes managed by BBC with HD channels, not the others.The rules say the SI tables must be cleartext EXCEPT EIT contents and BBC got permission to do this (presumably to make it awkward for people recording their HD channels). It is decodeable - you need the tables, and there are solutions to be found on the net.